# Ubuntu Emergency Mode after Removal of Several Packages - App Armor Fails to Load Profiles

Tags: boot, mount, fstab, apparmor, boost

I was recently trying to install the Boost CPP libraries via `sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev`. It had ask to remove several packages, so I mistakenly said yes to that prompt. Only after did I realize that several prominent packages were gone, including several ubuntu libraries. When I tried to reboot my computer, it entered into emergency mode and returned the output

```
[ TIME ] Timed out waiting for device /dev/disk/by-uuid/56D3-ED3F.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for
File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/56D3-ED3F.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for /boot/efi.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for Local File Systems.
emergency.service
finalrd.service
console-setup.service
systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service systemd-update-utmp.service
systemd-resolved.service
[FATLED] Failed to start Load AppArmor profiles.
You are in emergency mode. After logging in, type “journalctl -xb” to view system logs, “systemctl reboot”, “systemctl default” or “exit” to boot into default mode.
Press Enter for maintenance
(or press Control-D to continue):
```

Then I log in with my password. `cat /etc/fstab` returns

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust waay to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# ‹file system> <mount point>   <type>  ‹options>      <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/nvme0n1p2 during installation
UUID=c8143cd9-5cfc-4eae-a634-51881a2e62a0 /              ext4    errors=remount-ro 0
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
UUID=56D3-ED3F /boot/efi        vfat      umask=0077    0       1
/swapfile                                   none         swap   sw                  0       0
```

`blkid` returns

```
/dev/nvme0n1p1: UUID="56D3-ED3F" BLOCKSIZE="S12" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL"EFI System Partition" PARTUUID="2bafb09c-7bo3-47b9-b13a-b17736215c71"
/dev/nvme0n1p2: UUID="c8143cd9-5cfc-4eae-a634-51881a2e62a0" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="f18e5ddb-cec1-4c1e-8fa5-f57ffc64c63a"
[some other device mounts]
```

`systemctl --failed` returns

```
  UNIT                     LOAD           ACTIVE SUB       DESCRIPTION
* apparmor.service         loaded         failed failed    Load AppArmor profiles

LOAD   = Reflects whether the unit definition was properly loaded.
ACTIVE = The high-level unit activation state, i.e. generalization of SUB.
SUB    = The low-level unit activation state, values depend on unit type.
```

So it seems that by uninstalling these libraries I am unable to reboot properly because AppArmor was screwed up (and potentially other things were corrupted as well).
I am not able to uninstall the libboost package and reinstall the removed pacakges because it seems that there is no WiFi connection in this booting terminal.

Couuld sommeone please assist me? Even just "App Armor Fails to Load Profiles" barely has any documentation online. I am running Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS on a Lambda Tensorbook. Let me know what other information I need to provide.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Quick question: did you manually type out the content of your `/etc/fstab` file or copy/paste it? Reason I ask is because if your boot mount point is defined as `/boot/ef1`, then you will certainly have some issues. It should read `/boot/efi` 

Comment: I manually typed it out, it really is ef1.

Comment: Hi, can I get a bump on this?

Comment: The reason I asked the question about `ef1` (with a 1) is because the first set of errors said `Dependency failed for /boot/efi`. `ef1` is not a standard name, as it should be `efi` (for **E**xtensible **F**irmware **I**nterface). Editing the `/etc/fstab` file to use the proper name may be all you need to do.

Comment: @matigo Sorry I was also being clumsy in that comment. It really was `efi`, not `ef1`, so that's not the issue unfortunately.

Comment: I wonder if there is a new profile in `/etc/apparmor.d/` that is causing that system to fail. The failure to find the EFI partition is bizarre, though. Unless the UUID has changed (which `blkid` shows did not), it should come in just fine. I'm surprised you haven't nuked the system and reinstalled from scratch just to get it working again 